# Combining Columns on Blank Rows

Tags: sql

I have a question about the possibility of combining columns based on blanks ('') in a row.  The reason behind this is because I am using a charindex to strip off the middle initial in the first name.  However, if the data does not contain a middle initial I have it set to return a blank ('').
Here is an example of what I am looking to do.

```
First_Name     First_Name2   Column_Needed
John B         John          John
Fred                         Fred
Mary D         Mary          Mary
Mike                         Mike
Scott S        Scott         Scott
```

I would like to have a third column that would combine the two columns as one column with no blanks and no middle initials but all first names.

Some example of the code I am using to strip middle initial...

```
LEFT([First_Name], CHARINDEX(' ', [First_Name])) AS [First_Name2]
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to use a CASE statement in SQL:

```
SELECT CASE LEFT([First_Name], CHARINDEX(' ', [First_Name])) WHEN '' THEN [First_Name] ELSE LEFT([First_Name], CHARINDEX(' ', [First_Name])) END as Column_Needed
```

@Joseph B's is a much better answer.

Comment: Worked perfectly, I knew I needed a case statement but couldn't get the syntax right.  THANKS!

Comment: Try @Joseph B's answer, it might work and is much more clear.

Answer (score 1):

You can use the COALESCE function to get the First Name without the middle initial, as below:

```
SELECT COALESCE([First_Name2], [First_Name]) as Column_Needed
```